# create a custom partitioner in cassandra to index the record to specific nodes

Tags: cassandra

Currently i am using a Cassandra cluster with several nodes,

**Scenario:** While inserting the records i need to make sure that the specific row got inserted to the specified node. can i handle this be creating a custom partition? or is there any partitioner available to handle such things?

This is because when adding a new node to my cluster if there is an overflow or too much data , all the up coming insertions should be done in the new node. so i need the above scenario to be working. is this possible with Cassandra?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, by supplying an implementation of `org.apache.cassandra.dht.IPartitioner` and referencing the class name in `conf/cassandra.yaml` on the `partitioner:` field.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this. It's a very bad idea.

The effect will be that your new node will be completely hammered while all your old nodes do nothing. Your performance will be limited by that of the new node. Secondly, unless your replication factor is 1 your new row will be written to a number of nodes - this is what you want.

I would suggest reading the Cassandra documentation at datastax.com some more.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you this, but your solution seems to me to be the worst thing you could do to cassandra.

But rejoice, Cassandra 1.2 has introduced VNodes http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2

This should make inserting a new node in the cluster to relieve global load a bit quicker without hammering the new node (bear in mind that the new node has a lot to do beside taking in writes and reads when you bring it up). You just have to be smart about your initial setup of the token ring (with Vnodes) to make insertion of news nodes faster.

Your approach is very similar to what has been done by companies that use manually sharded MySQL servers. Manual sharding is the main problem you try to solve with systems like Cassandra.

I have seen two cases of cassandra not being able to cope with the load :

1. Your whole cluster is overload in which case bringing new nodes is the only way out. VNodes are your friend in this case. This is mainly due because you underestimated the load of you app. Make the cluster bigger or make the instances bigger that's your choice.
2. You have one node in the cluster that is being hammered in particular : this is a sign that your app is doing something very wrong, which is writing to one (or very few) hardcoded key. That will make all the reads and writes (for that key) fall on one node and overload it until crash and the rest of the cluster will try to take the load for it (worst case everything goes down, best case you will see a big fall in performance).
   The solution for this is to bucket your hard-coded key into many sub keys (enough that you can be sure that they will fall across the whole cluster, I advise generating their hash and check with nodetools for where they would fall).
   This last case is not solvable with sysops solutions and has to be fixed by going back into the code of the app that is hammering that key and fix it.

By the way the last case is exactly what would happen with the solution you would implement. A single cassandra instance is as good as the size of it (memory wize), they are not invincible. The fact that cassandra clusters are so amazing at having no single point of failure (if used correctly) is why cassandra can be used for taking of care huge workloads. Do not insert that single point of failure yourself.